# Get borderRadius from context

Tags: flutter, dart

From a given context, I managed to get the width, height and position of my widget. Now I would like to get the **borderRadius** too, do you know how to do it?

```
static Rect getWidgetBounds(BuildContext context) {
  final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;
  return (box != null) ? box.semanticBounds : Rect.zero;
}

static Offset getWidgetLocalToGlobal(BuildContext context) {
  final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;
  return box == null ? Offset.zero : box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
}
```

This is the Widget I'm trying to get the borders from :
https://github.com/flyerhq/flutter_chat_ui/blob/main/lib/src/widgets/message.dart

Comment: Can you include the widget  snippet, the one’s border you are trying to get?

Comment: Any idea sir???

Comment: Not sure but you can try using key.